# What actually happens when installing hardware drivers from a CD in Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers, installation

I am curious as to what happens in Windows in the background when you install device drivers from a CD for a particular piece of I/O.  My assumptions is that the only things that can be happening are transferring files to the drive form the CD, altering registry keys, and maybe changing some environment variables.

Is that all that happens in the background?  How exactly does the OS gain the ability to communicate to a device?  When I was young I used to think there was a fundamental difference between installing a program/driver from a CD and just inserting a CD and copying over files to specific directories, but now I'm not so sure there is any difference.

My questions arose because of my background in automated test equipment.  I was trying to develop a conceptual framework of understanding that when you connect a measurement instrument to a windows machine over GPIB or whatever, that you must install both hardware level drivers so that the OS can communicate with the device, but then you also install software drivers (API? libraries?) that you then use as part of a larger software package to compile a .dll that can be called programmatically to control the instrument. That got me wondering what is really the difference between installing the hardware-level driver for the OS, and installing software libraries for your automated test programs to use.

Are any of my assumptions and understanding just fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Why do you think installing a driver from a disk is different than installing drivers any other way?  Edit your question to provide the necessary clarification.  The end result is the .INF file is installed on the sytem.

Comment: Note, Microsoft has a good collection of documentation for those interested in writing drivers. Your question seems to me to indicate that you'd benefit from that sort of information too, and that's really where you'll find the answer to what drivers are and do: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/

Comment: This question is phrased too broadly for SuperUser.  It's not a bad question, just one better for a forum-style site, or asked of a college professor.  SuperUser is best suited for very specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

When hardware manufacturers write device drivers, they go through a rigorous process typically working directly with the author of the operating system (Microsoft or Apple, for example) using a software developer's kit supplied specifically tailored to their operating system(s).  Using standards, such as USB for example, allows relatively easy integration of hardware with the operating system.  It's up to other software developers, then, to implement the hardware devices, typically through API's (Application Program Interfaces) to interact with their own applications.

Obviously this is a very basic explanation, and it may be less than you wanted, but I saw no other answers listed, so I thought I'd share my view as a long-time programmer on the subject.

Comment: You don't actually have to work directly with Microsoft to write or produce a driver for Windows. Microsoft has published ADKs to assist with driver writing and has documented the hooks the drivers can access in the OS, but it is not necessary to work with them in any way to write a Windows driver. If you want the driver to be available over Microsoft Update for automated install, yes you'll have to work with them, but otherwise, that is not part of the process.

Answer (score 1):

It is just dropping files and writing entries in the registry and elsewhere. That's what a driver is.

It is what is in these files, and what is written to the registry that the driver does its work. The purpose of a driver is to communicate to the OS the nature and purpose of a device (physical or virtual) and tell the computer how to communicate with that device.

So these files and settings contain information the OS requires to send and receive information with the device.